# regex to match camelcase text mixed with certain conjunctions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match these sort of text in entirety -

```
Public Services
Access During Emergency 
Additional Rules and Regulations
Undue Loads, Heat, and Interference.
```

I am using this regex so far, but it completely doesn't work.

```
(([A-Z][a-z]+) (of|by|and|or)? ?([A-Z][a-z]+))
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you give an example of something you're trying to not match? Otherwise use `.*`.

Comment: The idea is to match titles in a document. So, typically, I am not trying to match text that ends like this "Public Services are" - that is indicative of a sentence and not a title.

Comment: would it be easier to split around a space, loop the strings returned by the split and check that every string starts with a capital letter, excluding of,by,or, and? just a suggestion

Comment: yea, I am willing to do it in code, if there is no regex to solve this.

Comment: I think the main problem with your pattern is that you aren't accounting for commas. Also you should probably group the optional space with the optional conjunctions, so they always appear together.

Comment: yes, I have to include commas

Comment: This is probably the most reliable way to do it https://regex101.com/r/F9UIG8/5 I'm guessing you don't really need the capturing groups.

Comment: Seems to be doing the trick! Please add as answer, will accept it.

Comment: it is failing to match this text though - Non-Disturbance Clause, even though I modified the regex to be this - (?:(?:[A-Z][a-z']+,?) )+(?:(?:of|by|and|or|for) )?(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)

Comment: Another text that it doesn't match - Testing, Validation and Mail Conditioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should cover all of your cases:

`^(?:(?:[A-Z][a-z]+,?)[ -])+(?:(?:of|by|and|or) )?(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)?`

https://regex101.com/r/F9UIG8/6